# Japanese equivalent to ASAP

Tags: expressions, english-to-japanese

What would the Japanese equivalent to ASAP be?

Would「急ぎでお願いします」be appropriate? 「すぐに」、「即に」just don't seem right.

Comment: The word form 即に doesn't exist. 即 is a standalone adverb.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are looking for a slang term used in business that actually **feels like "ASAP"**, we have:

> 「なる早{はや}」

which is short for 「なるべく早く」.  You can say:

> 「なる早でお願{ねが}いします。」

or just

> 「なる早で！」

[image]

Comment: What book is that from?

Comment: @istrasci [とっさのサラリーマン英語 日常会話インストール編](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A3%E3%81%95%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B5%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E-%E6%97%A5%E5%B8%B8%E4%BC%9A%E8%A9%B1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E7%B7%A8-%E3%83%87%E3%82%A4%E3%83%93%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%83%BB-%E3%82%BB%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3/dp/toc/4344016513) judging by the title of chapter 2

Comment: ASAPに対応する英語という回答の「なる早」を、質問者がベストアンサーとして受け取ったことに危惧します。「とっさのサラリーマン英語 日常会話インストール編 仕事モードで役立つ英語」で紹介されている意味は、日本語としていまだ認知性の低い、あるいは通用性価値の低い「なる早」に対応する英語がかろうじて通用性の高いASAPであるかもしれませんが、逆は成り立たないと思います。社会生活でASAP並みの通用価値で「なる早」を使うと、使った人の人格が疑われます。日本人が、日常の会話で、いわんやビジネス現場でこの言葉は使うとマイナスが多いでしょう。まして、外国の方がこれを使うことは絶対にやめた方が良いです。日本人でも使わない言葉ですから、外国の方がこの言葉を使っても意味が伝わらないと思います。この言葉を聞いた日本人の反応は多分：「うん？？」「何？？？」。

Comment: ^ まあでも、"If you are looking for **a slang term** " って、但し書きしてあるしぃ・・一応。。。

Answer (score 9):

I think there are quite a few acceptable ways to say it.
Here are a few of them I can think of.

> - 大至急
> - できるだけ早く lit. as soon as possible.
> - 出来る限り早期に lit. as soon as possible.
> - 今すぐ  used at my company as a status for tasks that have the highest priority.
> - できる限り早く lit. as soon as possible.
> - 一日も早く

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility to consider is 次第

> as soon as; immediately (upon)often after the -masu stem of a verb

(source: jisho.org)

E.g.

> 受け取り次第
>
> (Immediately) after receiving

which would definitely be a more appropriate thing to use in say, a business setting and with less strong demand-like emphasis than なる早 or なるべく早く